# ConfigureLogging MissingMethodException with 2.0.0 Preview 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I've upgraded my app to `2.0.0-preview1-final`, and, on `dotnet run` I receive the following:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureLogging(System.Action`2)'.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.ConfigureLogging(IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, Action'2 configureLogging)

Here is my `Main()`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var env = context.HostingEnvironment;

                config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                if (args != null)
                    config.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((factory) => {
                factory.AddConsole();
                factory.AddDebug();
            })
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

If I'm reading the [release notes from GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20milestone%3A2.0.0-preview1) correctly, according to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/238) and [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/241), what I'm doing above with `ConfigureLogging()` should be fine.

Comment: Are you using the .NET CLI (SDK) 2.0 preview1 as well? E.g. what does `dotnet --version` prints?

Comment: Yup. `dotnet --version` returns `2.0.0-preview1-005977`.

Comment: Take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157499/system-missingmethodexception-after-upgrading-from-2-0-0-preview1-final-to-2-0-0?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 projects in my solution; my application and two class libraries.  In my class libraries, I have references to a couple AspNetCore packages (such as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`).

The `2.0.0-preview1-final` packages (like the one mentioned above) have a dependency on `.NETCoreApp 2.0`. This caused some fuss in my class libraries (obviously, they aren't an app). Previously, they were only dependent on the `.NET Standard`. I pulled down the `2.0.0-preview3-*` packages from the nightly builds feed because they un-did the dependency on `.NETCoreApp` and target `.NET Standard` once again, but, kept the `2.0.0-preview1-final` references in my web project.

The different versions of packages are what caused the error.  I've moved any `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` package to target `2.0.0-preview3-*` across on my projects in the solution and it works.

Why it threw the `MissingMethodException` for `ConfigureLogging` on `WebHost`  build specifically?

I do not know.