# System.MissingMethodException after upgrading from 2.0.0-preview1-final to 2.0.0-preview2-final

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I just updated my visual studio to preview 4 and updated all my packages from Core 2.0 Preview 1 Final to Core 2.0 Preview 2 Final. Below is my `csproj` file after all upgradation.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.5.2-beta2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Humanizer.Core" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0.0-dev-10164" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Literate" Version="3.0.1-dev-00044" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Below is the raw exception details.

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.get_Configuration()'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup.ApplicationInsightsLoggerStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;

namespace Phoenix
{
    public class AppProgram
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .ConfigureLogging(factory =>
                {
                    factory.AddConsole();
                    factory.AddDebug();
                })
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs (I had to comment out `loggerFactory.AddSeriLog()` call because it was generating error just after I updated all the packages.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        // removed for brevity
    });

    // DI statements have been removed for brevity.

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });

}
```

As suggested in the error message from `loggerFactory.AddSerilog();`, I tried adding `services.AddSeriLog()` in my `ConfigureServices` method.

I also tried installing package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, also didn't fix.

I also tried replacing content of `Program.cs` file from the new template as below. This also didn't work.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Can someone please help me fixing this issue?

### Update

Adding package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` solves the issue. But I really do not want to add this package as this adds many unwanted references packaged into this single package.

Comment: Always read https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestone/13 before an upgrade, it has all the breaking changes of a new version :)

Comment: Thanks @Tseng, I just went through the breaking changes. Seems like they've not mentioned about this package change there. Anyway, at least now I know where to start for an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required package is

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration`

I added the package which resolved the issue.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
```

Comment: I've added this package but this time it gives an error like that:
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.